# Is there any way to set a method directly to the html view form in ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

In Controller.java i mapped an object **msg**

```
resultMap.put("msg", msg);
```

now, i want to print all the properties of the method in a html form using ajax call. And i'm doing it like this. Setting an id for each field of the html view form and then setting the method properties to them one by one.

```
$.ajax(
...
...
function (data) {
        $('#name').text(data.msg.name); 
        $('#age').text(data.msg.age);
        $('#gender').text(data.msg.gender);
        $('#class').text(data.msg.class);
        .....
        .....
);
```

But, in some cases there may be 20/30+ properties in a method. it is really hard to set id's in the form for all field and then set the method values to them in ajax.

**Is there any way to set the method directly to the html view form in ajax?**

Comment: since you are using jquery i'd suggest to use a template engine

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this fit for your needs, in a case like this i'd use a template engine like, [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js). Using this library,

First define an HTML root element in a `<script>` that you are going to use,

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <ul>
        <li>NAME: {{name}}</li>
        <li>AGE: {{age}}</li>
        <li>GENDER: {{gender}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Function to manipulate this `<ul>`.

```
function load() {
  var template = $('#template').html();
  Mustache.parse(template);
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {name: ajax_data, age: ajax_data, gender: ajax_data});
  $('#target').html(rendered);
}
```

You can place this function content in ajax `.success` block to access `data.msg.--` properties.